# using gmail app script replace message body based on subject line and forward email to customer's email but keep the attachment with the message

Tags: javascript

I have a need to forward messages with an order id and attached receipt to customers, I would like to automate this process. 
Since Yahoo webmail doesn't seem to offer me the ability to do it, I would like to script a solution using google apps script
unfortunately I cannot seem to wrap my head around their Api well enough to figure out how to pull it off.

I have setup imap access to the yahoo account and I forward the message from yahoo to gmail. Once the message hits gmail, I have a label filter attached in my inbox that puts it in a folder for me, problem I am having is I cannot workout how to regex the subject line to find the message, then after I find it, how do I strip out the contents (body) of the message? I want to keep the attachment the body itself though should be stripped and replaced with a confirmation message, which also needs some customizing prior to getting sent out. I have downloaded the simple mail merge which will hopefully handle the message interpolation with unique data for the outgoing message but I am still stuck on the attachment and the finding of the subject line.

Any suggestions welcome, I am going thru the tutorials and stuff for gmail script but so far have not found anything that will help me figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for tutorial or someone to write it? do you have any code so far?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please have a look at [What questions should be asked on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)